try in to connect to local docker postgres but geting FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
docker command
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 -d -p 5432:5432 postgres

 psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres

when password is asked i gave the correct password but geting
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" , port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" connection to server at "localhost", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
i am tring to connect to database with the db connection URL

(1) Can't reproduce your error. (2) Same Command in Host, docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 -p 5432:5432 -d postgres , then run psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres input password: 123 , is ok , (3) my psql version:  psql (12.19 (Ubuntu 12.19-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), server 16.3 (Debian 16.3-1.pgdg120+1))  (4) docker ps, find container id, run docker exec -it 740dfe65bba4 psql -U postgres is OK, too.

POSTGRES_PASSWORD environment  variable only take action when you are initialize your cluster. if you are trying to run container on datadir that already exist that env variable not going to be used (because password already setted up earlier, at first run on the datadir). it seems you are not using volumes, so probably it is not your case, but if you are decided just not show to us your actual docker run command and removed -v option before putting it here, it's probably your case.

Thank you. I’m using WSL on Windows 10 and Docker Desktop for Windows. For some reason, when I try to connect to the container from WSL, the error keeps occurring. when I'm using a cloud database service provider it is working fine. I've ensured that Docker is running and WSL integration is enabled.
